# Skip row starting with "@" with read.table() in R

Tags: r, read.table

I would like to read a file within `R` with the function `read.table()`.
My input data are big files of around `25Go` so I would like the most efficient way to do what I want.

The first lines of my file (I don't know how many, since it depends on the file) starts with "`@`" which is the header of my file and I would like to skip all these lines.

I haven't found anything relevant to my problem since all the solutions
consider to skip a definite number of rows, which is not what I want.

I found something about `comment.char` but it's not working for
what I want,

I tried like this:

```
dat <- read.table(file.name, header=FALSE, comment.char="@", sep="\t")
```

***edit :***

exemple input:

```
@HD VN:1.4  SO:coordinate
@SQ SN:chr1 LN:249250621
@SQ SN:chr2 LN:243199373
...
9754R:04158:11144   0   chr1    10002   0
2MBNV:09647:08301   0   chr1    10060   2
```

and here is the error i get :

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     line 1 did not have 2 elements
>   Calls: read.table -> scan
>   Execution halted

Comment: Did you try to specify the separator, does the separator appear in the first lines ?

Comment: Try `readr::read_table` with the options: `comment = '@',skip_empty_rows = T` . Also, `data.table::fread` may skip them automatically.

Comment: Did you try setting `comment.char = ""`? From the docs: Using comment.char = "" will be appreciably faster than the read.table default. Maybe this is fast enough. And filtering the elements starting with `@` is much simpler once the data is inside a data.frame..

Comment: Please provide example file.

Comment: `read.table(file.name, header=F, comment.char="@")` worked for me (no `sep='\t'`).

Comment: indeed it's actually working... i actually wanted to select specific column form my file and I didn't expected it but the problem is coming from there...